# Function which finds temperatures for a given month from data

Tags: matlab, function, datetime, filtering, vectorization

I'm having some issues creating a function with the following parameters:

```
Ndata = extperiod(data, year, month,time)
```

The data is a table with 3 columns, which from left to right are:

```
year/month/date,   time,   temperature
```

My goal is to create a function which can extract a time and a year/month, irrespective of the date and find it's corresponding temperature.

- I need to avoid using `for` loops
- I've been advised to use `floor` and `find`, where `floor(YYYYMMDD/100) = YYYY*100 + MM`, which I somehow want to integrate to my function.

I've previously found a way to extract all temperatures from the data for a given day, as follows:

```
k = find(data(:,1)==19750101);    
data(k(1):k(end),3)
```

I'm trying to incorporate this method, but I think that the hint "`floor(YYYYMMDD/100)`" throws me a of a little.

I have tried with `find(data(:,1)==floor(YYYYMMDD/100))`, where I would think that I'd be given all dates with a specific year and month. For example:

```
find( data(:,1) == floor(19660101/100) )
```

I thought this would give me all points in the column vector where the value is 196601. But it doesn't.

What could I try differently?

Comment: Start by using `for` loops! They are simple to grasp, and you can write code which *works*. Then you can show us some code as a [MCVE], with a subset of your data table, expected inputs, and the corresponding expected outputs. Vectorising exsiting code to remove `for` loops is then semantics at the end. Unless this is for an assignment (in which case you might be able to get assistance from a classmate/supervisor), there is no reason to prematurely avoid loops.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, your want to get all temperature for a given month, no matter time and day.

So you want to find dates that are comprised in the range `[YYYYMM ; YYYY{MM+1}[` or `[YYYYMM ; {YYYY+1}01[` in the case of selecting December.
Recall that you store the complete date in your table. So you need to apply your operator `floor` to both sides of your query, not only on the query value, because no date is `floor(YYYYMMDD/100)`!

As a result, try the following:

```
find( floor(data(:,1)/100) == floor(19660101/100) )
```

Comment: You're totally right, I now see why `find( data(:,1) == floor(19660101/100) )` does not work. Because there are no dates in my datafile with the format YYYYMM. Now I just have to find a certain time for all days in a month, but this gave me very good basis. Thank you for that. Would you mind if I used this post for future inquriry regarding this problem?

Comment: @JonnyCola If you have subsequent questions, best is to ask a new question (if you don't find the answer on SO already of course!).